# ActiveX Comboboxes in Excel 365 don't work

Tags: microsoft-excel, activex, microsoft-excel-365

I have a sheet with some activeX comboboxes. They work properly in Excel  2013. Now I have an Excel - office 365 - version 1808 - build 10730.20264. When I open this very sheet, comboboxes do not respond to clicks (I mean they don't dropdown). Also, everytime I click in a combobox, Excel shows another freezed image of an empty combobox elsewhere on the screen. Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by quick repairing office through control panel.
I have followed these instructions:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b